# Akka stream each element to ftp sink

Tags: akka-stream

I want to write each element in an Akka stream to a (different) FTP file. Using Alpakka I can write each element to the same file using an FTP sink. However I can not seem to figure out how to write each element to a different file.

```
source.map(el -> /* to byte string */).to(Ftp.toPath("/file.xml", settings));
```

So every `el` should end up in a different file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the Alpakka FTP sink, you have to do something along the lines of

```
  def sink(n: String): Sink[String, NotUsed] = Ftp.toPath(s"$n.txt", settings)

  source.runForeach(s ⇒ Source.single(s).runWith(sink(s)))
```

otherwise, you'll need to create your own sink that establishes an FTP connection and writes the data as part of the input handler. You'll need to create your own graph stage to do it. More info about this can be found in the [docs](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/stream-customize.html?language=java).